Unable to create an Île-de-France Mobilites Connect account
I'm traveling to Paris soon, and want to buy a Navigo weekly pass. To do this, I need to create an Île-de-France Mobilites Connect account. However, it's not allowing me to accept the terms and conditions.
Steps I've taken:

Create a new account, upon clicking this button it would throw an error (Error 15).




I could circumvent this by activating my VPN (I use WindScribe) and setting my location to France.

Fill in the user information (the 'Next' button remains gray until I've filled in all the fields)




Choose a password



Accept the terms and conditions


This is where I get stuck. Even if I accept the terms by ticking the checkbox, and scroll to the bottom of the text, the 'Confirm' button remains grey and disabled.
I'm not sure what I should do to be able to accept the terms and conditions. I have this issue with various browsers, on my phone and laptop, and I cannot pinpoint what is causing the problem.
##addendum##
I've also tried to purchase the weekly pass via the Bonjour RATP app. These are the steps I've gone through:

Select the 'tickets' in the RATP app, which shows this screen, Select 'Forfaits Navigo'.



Select 'Navigo Weekly Pass'



Select 'Buy'


4.Select 'Continue'


This brings me back to the IDFM landing page.



The homepage mentions a captcha and I see one on my machine. The button only becomes active after successfully completing the challenge. Trying on several devices makes this less likely but is it possible you have some sort of ad block or anti-tracking extension that's interfering with this captcha?

Another idea: Have you tried the Bonjour RATP app? An IDF Mobilités account is necessary for the Navigo Liberté+ product but I think you should be able to load a weekly pass on a Navigo card or a phone without creating any account. You can also definitely do that from the ticket machines at any station in the Paris area.

@Relaxed thanks for the help. From the source code of the website, I do see a Captcha block, but it is indeed not rendering.  I've disabled my Adblocker, but I'm still not able to get it to show. Not sure what I can do to force it.
I also tried it via the Bonjour RATP app, but it also redirected me to the IDF mobilite Connect login.

If I force the button to the enabled state and then click it, it throws a Captcha not completed error, so that seems to be the issue. Leaves only the question of why it's not rendered properly on my side.
The one thing I can think of is that my VPN (Windscribe) is somehow filtering/interfering with the Captcha, but I have no way of validating this hypothesis.

When is Bonjour RATP redirecting you to the login and on what platform? I just checked on my phone (iOS) and I am able to scan a Navigo Easy pass without being logged in (did not try to buy anything today but that's also how I buy my monthly pass usually).

@Relaxed, I've added screenshots showing the process on the Bonjour RATP app.

This is an Android phone, right? On iOS, the “Tickets” tab starts with a choice between “On my phone” (which was only available on Android initially) and “On my Navigo pass” (which is only available on iOS, I think). “On my phone” works exactly as pictured but “On my Navigo pass” allows you to buy tickets without ever logging in. You do need a physical Navigo Easy pass of course.

Yes, this is on an Android. I wanted to avoid getting a physical card, but it seems unavoidable. In that case I could also just purchase it when I arrive in Paris and avoid all this :)

Captchas are sometimes hosted on third-party sites, so browser rules blocking cross-site inclusion might have an effect. I'm not sure I'd recommend disabling security settings but you might be able to try it briefly.

@StuartF, I would be willing to try this, but unsure how to do it in Chrome. Do you know where I could find a reference how to do it?

I just tried it on the iPhone of my partner and it lead to the same result (non-showing of the Captcha), so it's consistent across phone brands and OS. Later today I'll be in France so I can try it without VPN.

Just for information, I was very upset because I tried many times and I had also same problem. Then, using a VPN with France server IP, I opened the page to create the account with Microsoft Edge and the captcha was there and finally I could finish the process. I was very upset, I lost more than one hour!
They did a very bad work and they didn't mentioned that you can create the account only with a french IP address and using MS Edge...
Really bad work with their poor HTML page.

The captcha works when you switch to 'French'. See my answer below.

you can get the pass in person once you arrive in France

As far as I understand it, visitors are expected to get a pass navigo découverte, which is a physical card and cannot be obtained online

WindScribe was the issue as it was filtering the Captcha. When using a different VPN provider the Captcha loads correctly.
I found this out after I came back from the trip, I'm leaving my other findings below for reference.
I got a physical card from the desk and loaded the weekly subscription onto it. This cannot be purchased from the machine, as you need a personalized card.
Note of caution: two people in our group managed to load a ticket on their phone. One had no issues, the other had problems after two days. The ticket was suddenly not present anymore, and reloading it caused an error. We went to several service desks, but none of them was able to solve this issue. This meant that for the remaining 5 days, they had no valid ticket even though they paid for it. It might be worth it to avoid all this by getting a physical ticket (extra cost of €2).
Troubleshooting:
When I got to France, I tried to open the account registration page, but it still threw the Error 15 page. The same error was thrown when I was connected to the EuroStar wifi.
Only when I was connected to the wifi of my Airbnb was I able to get to the registration page again and the Captcha loaded.
For future reference, this is how the page of step 5. of the question is supposed to look like:


(+1) Windscribe has a bunch of filtering options (“R.O.B.E.R.T”), did you try fiddling with those?

I've tried several things, but no success so far. I think I've turned all filtering off, and still, it's not loading. I'll try to find another VPN to cross-check.

@Relaxed, I tried it with a different VPN provider and now the Captcha is loading. So that confirms it was an issue with WindScribe

Had the same problem; found that switching to 'French' when creating the account solved the issue (using Chrome).
Note that you will also need a bit later a french mobile phone number for supposed 'identity verification' via SMS, the start of the number with +33 is enforced.
